# HDFS:How to distribute files of small sizes across?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata

I have very large number of small files to be stored in HDFS. Based on the file name I want to store them in different data nodes. This way I can achieve file names starting with certain alphabets to go into specific data nodes. How to do this in Hadoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a very good choice. Reasons :

- Hadoop is not very good at handling very large number of small files.
- Storing one complete file in a single node is against one of the fundamental principles of HDFS, **distributed storage**.

I would like to know what benefit will you get with this approach.

---

In response to your comment :

HDFS doesn't do any kind of sorting like HBase does. When you put a file into HDFS, it gets split into small blocks first and then gets stored(each block on a different node). So there is nothing like sending a whole file to a single node. Your file(blocks) reside on multiple nodes.

What you could do is create a directory hierarchy as per you needs and store files in those directories(in case your intention is to fetch the files directly based on their location). **For example,**

```
/dirA
/dirA/A.txt
/dirA/B.txt
/dirB
/dirB/P.txt
/dirB/Q.txt
/dirC
/dirC/Y.txt
/dirC/Z.txt
```

But, if you really want to send the blocks of a particular file to some specific nodes then you need to implement your own block placement policy and which is not very easy. See **[this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-385)** for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.I wanted to forward files belonging to many types into different DataNodes so as to minimize data transmission later.

Comment: You are welcome Vinodh. Data transmission as in transmission within the cluster or between the cluster and some outside machine?

Comment: When I place the files first time right in the cluster according to alphabetical or other order(My assumption was HDFS allows routing just like HBase does) later I do not have to move anything across the cluster.( Data transmission as in transmission within the cluster)